# Why should I prefer Invoke-DbaQuery to its alternatives?

Tags: sql-server, command-line, dbatools, feature-comparison

[The documentation](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery.html) for `Invoke-DbaQuery` mentions many other similar functions

> This function is a wrapper command around `Invoke-DbaAsync`, which in turn is based on `Invoke-SqlCmd2`. It was designed to be more convenient to use in a pipeline and to behave in a way consistent with the rest of our functions.

There are of course other ways to query SQL from PowerShell, e.g. `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.

What are the benefits of using `Invoke-DbaQuery` instead of `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, `Invoke-Sqlcmd2`, and `Invoke-DbaAsync`?

Comment: One feature with `Invoke-DbaQuery` that I use for is multi instance query. No need of explicit loop structure to execute the same on bunch of instances.

Comment: @S.D. Flesh that out with examples and it would be a decent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One feature with `Invoke-DbaQuery` is, it accepts collection of
   instances for invoking a query. And, no need of explicit loop
   construct to execute a query or script file unlike `invoke-sqlcmd` does need.

```
    $instances = @('SqlInstance01', 'SqlInstance02')
    $sql = "select @@servername as InstanceName"
    
    #Explicit for loop, without which it throws an exception
    $instances | %{invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $_ -Query $sql}
    
    InstanceName
    ------------
    SqlInstance01
    SqlInstance02
    
    Import-Module dbatools
    #No explicit loop specified
    Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $instances -Query $sql
    
    InstanceName
    ------------
    SqlInstance01
    SqlInstance02
```

2. There are bunch of other usecases it supports where as `invoke-sqlcmd` doesn't. Especially taking pipeline inputs, refer to examples section here [Invoke-DbaQuery](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery.html#:%7E:text=NoExec%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%2DEnableException%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%3CCommonParameters%3E%5D-,Examples,-Example%3A%201).